# sharing product on facebook

Tags: product, product-images, facebook

It cant find any information about this, but when I share my products on Facebook, my picture is not the correct one. How can I "force" it to take the product image?

I want it to use the picture of the product.

Here is a product http://www.ifp.dk/lederkonferencen-2016-ledelse-pa-topniveau.html

Hope you can help me!

Comment: try this http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/simple-social-sharing-buttons-in-magento/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Lederkonferencen 2016 - Styrk dine lederkompetencer" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ifp.dk/lederkonferencen-2016-styrk-dine-lederkompetencer.html" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Få inspiration og personlige værktøjer fra landets dygtigste topledere og erhvervsfolk. Konferencen giver unikke muligheder for networking, sparring og dialog med ligesindede. Riv en dag ud af kalenderen og lær af succesfulde erhvervsledere." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ifp.dk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/l/e/lederkonferencen-annoncebillede.jpg" />
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will, by default, look for Open Graph tags in the `<head>` of the page, for example:

`<meta content="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/13109009_1587433394900367_1920764561_n.jpg" property="og:image" />`

Failing this, it'll scrape the page for `<img>` elements.

You'll probably need an extension for this, or [refer to this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58729/manually-install-open-graph-tag) here for a more manual approach.

**Resources**

- [Webmasters - Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement image meta tag like `<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />` to specify which image to take while sharing the product. 
You can read more OG tags and FB sharing on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the on Facebook, you can manually load the picture. If you want Facebook to automatically pick the right photo, you need to follow, you need to add it to the open graph tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this to work when users share a product from your catalog. Facebook has good documentation on how to make sure the right image is used:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

You can also manually add a photo as you post.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]= set product url here&p[images][0]=set product image here&p[title]=set product name here&p[summary]=set product description here

use above url and set product value as describe in url.